# My cookie isn't working when I revisit the page

Tags: javascript, redirect, cookies

When people type in my URL, I want them to click North Carolina or Virginia. After they click, it redirects them to either www.myurl.com/nc or www.myurl.com/va. After they answer that question, next time they visit my site, it will redirect them to the appropriate page without clicking NC or VA again. My links are working (taking me to the correct page) but when I return, the cookie is not redirecting me and i'm returning to the same page where I ask to choose the state.  Here's what I've got so far. I feel like I'm close, but I honestly have no clue what I'm doing.

```
<p> Please tell us where you live so we can give you information for your location. </p>
<a href="#" onClick="window.location = 'http://www.myurl.com/nc'" value="nc">North Carolina</a><br />
<br />
<a href="#" onClick="window.location = 'http://www.myurl.com/va'" value="va">Virginia</a> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
function redirect(state) {     createCookie('state', state, 90);     window.location.href = "http://www.myurl.com/" + nc; } 
</script>
```

I also have this script in a separate file:

```
// JavaScript Document
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

Comment: Are you using a JavaScript debugging tool like Firebug or Chrome's built-in tools?

Comment: I don't see you calling `redirect()` anywhere...

Comment: where would I put the call for redirect?  In my separate script file?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<p> Please tell us where you live so we can give you information for your location. </p>
<a href="#" onClick="redirect('nc');return false" >North Carolina</a><br />
<br />
<a href="#" onClick="redirect('va');return false" >Virginia</a> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
function redirect(state) {
    createCookie('state', state, 90);
    window.location.href = "http://www.myurl.com/" + state; 
}
var cookie = readCookie('state');
if (cookie != null) {
    window.location.href = "http://www.myurl.com/" + cookie;
}
</script>
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7j8pG/1/

Comment: Thank you - that works as far as redirecting me to the correct page.  But when I revisit the page, it doesn't redirect me to the correct page - i have to select the state again.  I want the cookie to set so it remembers and I won't have to click the state every time (kind of like craigslist).

Comment: Thanks for all your help.  It works fine in firefox, but in ie, it redirects to VA before i even get a chance to click.  Also, when i revisit the page, it briefly shows the page with NC and VA options and then redirects.  is there a way to make it redirect so it doesn't show that splash page?  You've been a big help.  Thanks so much.

Comment: @dkype - In ie it's probably doing that because you already have a cookie set for va. To get it to not show the page briefly, you have to use php

Comment: @dkype - Try this php code at the top of the page, before the doctype or html: `<?php if ($_COOKIE['state'] == 'va') { header( 'Location: http://www.myurl.com/va' ); } else if ($_COOKIE['state'] == 'nc') { header( 'Location: http://www.myurl.com/nc' ); } ?>`

Comment: yes!  That worked,  thank you.  I actually still see the page briefly, even using the php...it redirects a lot faster with the php than it did with just the javascript.  if you know of a way to eliminate seeing the page at all, that would be amazing, but if not - i appreciate your help and will just leave it like that.  thank you thank you thank you.

Comment: I'm an idiot.  I was trying to make the php code work in a html file.  I changed it and of course, everything works perfectly.  Thanks so much for your help.